# Passing a scanner as a perameter to a Java Method

Tags: java, class, methods, java.util.scanner

I'm fairly new to programming and newer still to Java.

I'm trying to write some code that will take input from a user and create a new object (instance?) from it. The concept is adding and updating a student info system. So the user is presented a menu (made up of switch statements) and they choose an option and that int choice number calls the method that is supposed to add, update or view the student.

I have two classes: StudentSystem and Student. StudentSystem does most of the work. Student, obviously is the Class that defines the details of the student object we are to create.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentSystem {

    boolean exit = false;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StudentSystem menu = new StudentSystem();
        menu.runMenu();

    }


    public void runMenu()
    {
        printHeader();
        while (!exit)
        {
            printOptions();
            int choice = getInput();
            executeChoice(choice);
        }
    }
    public void printHeader()
    {
        System.out.println("+-------------------------------------- +");
        System.out.println("|             Welcome to the            |");
        System.out.println("|          Student Admin System         |");
        System.out.println("+-------------------------------------- +");

    }
    public void printOptions()
    {

        System.out.println("\n1: Add Student");
        System.out.println("2: Update Student");
        System.out.println("3: View Student");
        System.out.println("0: Exit");
    }

    private int getInput() {
        Scanner keyInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = -1; // Set to -1 so that the number is outside the number choice. This way it will not conflict.
        while (choice < 0 || choice > 2) {
            try {
                System.out.print("\nPlease make a Selection: ");
                choice = Integer.parseInt(keyInput.nextLine());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                System.out.println("You have made an invalid selection. Please try again.");
            }
        }
        return choice;
    }
    private void executeChoice(int choice) { // Executes the choice provided.
        switch (choice) {
            case 0:
                exit = true;
                System.out.println("Thank you for using the Student Admin System.\nGoodbye! ");
                break;
            case 1:
                addStudent();
                break;
            case 2:
                // updateStudent();
            case 3:
                // viewStudent();
            default:
                System.out.println("Does not compute!");

        }
    }
    public static void addStudent(){ /**/This is just a minor attempt at what method should go here.**
        Student mystudent = new Student("Harry", 10,3.0, 'B');
        System.out.println(mystudent);
    }

}
```

**Here is the Student Class:**

```
public class Student {

    private static Student newStudent;
    String name;
    int age;
    double gpa;
    char grade;

    public Student(String name, int age, double gpa, char grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}
```

Most of the code in StudentSystem can be ignored, but it might give some context. The stuck point is creating a method that is called when you choose an option under executeChoice that creates a student object that can be viewed and edited. The extra tricky pary is adding/manipulating the name, grade, major etc also through user input. I could just type it into the method like I did in the addStudent method, but that wouldn't be very helpful or dynamic.

I'm thinking i could use a method like:

```
public static void userChoice(Scanner keyInput) {
        
   <some code>
}
```

But I'm not sure exactly how I would write it.

Hope it kinda makes sense what I'm trying to accomplish. Any advice would be greatly appriciated. I'm here to learn.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why you would need to pass Scanner object to a method to update student details